# $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n^2)^n$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + C/n^\alpha)^n$, no logarithms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How would I go about computing the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n^2)^n$ without using logarithms? I have tried messing around with the binomial theorem but I have not got anywhere. Also let $\alpha$ be fixed. For which $\alpha$ do I obtain the same limit for $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + C/n^\alpha)^n$ where $C > 0$ is an arbitrary constant (again, no logarithms)? Again, I feel like I'm supposed to use the binomial theorem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C > 0$, $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Then$$\left(1 + {C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\left( {C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^k \ge 1 + {{nC}\over{n^\alpha}} \ge 1 + Cn^{1 - \alpha},$$which goes to $+\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now assume $C > 0$, $\alpha > 1$. Then$$\left(1 + {C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\left( {C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^k = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}\left( {C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^k \le 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty n^k\left({C\over{n^\alpha}}\right)^k $$$$\le 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (Cn^{1-\alpha})^k = 1 + {{Cn^{1-\alpha}}\over{1 - Cn^{1-\alpha}}}.$$As $n \to \infty$, $Cn^{1-\alpha} \to 0$ so$$1 + {{{Cn}^{1 - \alpha}}\over{1 - Cn^{1 - \alpha}}} \to 1 + {0\over{1 - 0}} = 1.$$Thus $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (C/n^\alpha)^n \le 1$. Also, $(1 + C/n^\alpha)^n \ge 1$, so $\liminf_{n \to \infty} (1 + C/n^\alpha)^n \ge 1$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + C/n^\alpha)^n = 1$.

It is worthwhile to consider the following two questions on $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + C/n^\alpha)^n$ when $\alpha = 1$:

1. Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + C/n^\alpha)^n$ exist?
2. Does it depend on $C$? $($I wonder what this means for the previous question$\dots)$

Answer (score 3):

An idea by hints:

Using that

$$a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\implies\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e$$

we get that

$$\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e$$

Now prove the following easy lemma (for example, using the squeeze theorem):

**Lemma:** If $\;a_n>0\;$ and $\;a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}L>0\;,\;\;L\neq\infty\;$ , then $\;\sqrt[n]{a_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$

Solve your problem now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = \sqrt[n]{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}} \to e^{0} = 1$.

Assume $\alpha > 0$, taking $\ln$:

$\dfrac{\ln\left(1+C\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\alpha}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \dfrac{\ln\left(1+Cx^{\alpha}\right)}{Cx^{\alpha}}\cdot \dfrac{C}{x^{1-\alpha}} \to 0$ $\text{if}$  $\alpha > 1$, and $\infty$ $\text{if}$ $\alpha < 1$