# $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{n^{p}})^{n}$ for $p< 1$ and $p > 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061164/lim-n-to-infty-1-1-n2n-lim-n-to-infty-1-c-n-alphan-n)
answers $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n^{p}})^{n}$ for $p< 1$ and $p > 1$

Is there a similar approach for the one below, or an approach that adapts what the link shows?

$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{n^{p}})^{n}$ for $p< 1$ and $p > 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $p,q>0$, as $n$ goes to $+\infty$,
$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^{p}}\right)^{n^q}=\exp\left(n^q\ln(1 - \frac{1}{n^{p}})\right)\sim\exp(-n^{q-p})$$
(because $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ when $x$ goes to $0$).
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^{p}}\right)^{n^q}=
\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        0, & \text{if $q>p$, } \\
        1, & \text{if $q<p$, }\\
        e^{-1}, & \text{if $q=p$. } 
        \end{array}\right.
$$